# How, or best way to run while loop to avoid API limitations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, background, sidekiq

I am using an API request and this API has a limit of 2 calls a second and 250 records per request.  That's the gist.

I have created this background job that also has the option of a second background job.  This may be overkill.

Flow:

1. Order webhooks on creates from shopify
2. Cron job once per day for that days orders in case webhooks fail.

Goal for request:

If there are `>= 250` records/orders in the first API request, to then create a second background job in a new worker to fetch page 2 in about 3 minutes, and if page 2 has `>= 250`, to then create a new background job in the same worker has page 2 (after 2 completes) 3 minutes after page 2 jobs started fetch page 3, and so on..  I use `n` for the page and add `1` to `n` if the 250 statement is true.

**Cron Job:**

```
 shops = Shop.all
  shops.map do |shop|
    if shop.company.present?
      ShopifyOrderUpdatesWorker.perform_later(shop)
    end 
  end
```

**Background job 1:** (for first API call)

```
      def perform(shop)
        n = 1
        orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, params: {created_at_min: 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day.iso8601}, limit: 250, page: n )
        while (orders.count >= 250) || n == 1
          unless n =< 1 
            while n > 1 && orders.count >= 250
              orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, params: {created_at_min: 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day.iso8601 }, limit: 250, page: n)
              #while orders.count >= 250 || n == 2
                t = 3
ShopifyOrderUpdatesLimitWorker.delay_for(t.minutes).perform_later(orders)
                n += 1 #add page to API call request
                t += +3 #add 3 minutes for each loop to buffer the api call queue to avoid api limits to be safe
              #end
            end
          end
          if n == 1
            orders.map do |order|
              #code here
            end
          end
          n += 1
        end
      end
```

**Background job 2:** (for any API call after the first)

```
  def perform(orders)
    orders.map do |order|
      #code here
    end
  end
```

This way, all shops can update "quickly" without being in queue behind other shops.  Shops that have a lot of orders will wait the same time they would in either case of doing all of this in one action or in 2.

Is this overkill? Done right for code

In reality, it is probably very rare a webhook will fail so the chances of the second background job being called is slim.

Any possible improvements or suggestions for the code?

This may not be the right place to ask this question, but if anyone has experience with shopify or similar api situations, what are you doing?

Comment: Quick note - you'll get an N+1 issue in your Cron code as is. Switch to `shops = Shop.includes(:company)` or `if shop.company_id.present?` (the latter will be more performant) to overcome this :)

Comment: Can you explain? I tested it without errors for a dev shop but the shop only had a few dozen orders

Comment: lmao had to look that one up.  Wasn't familiar.  Thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sleep(30) if ShopifyAPI.credit_maxed?
```

add this in your loop

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  With this I can remove the need for a second background worker.  What you rckon?

Comment: actually i am currently working in a project where such shopify_api  are used which needed constant and continues calls so i had idea about this, glad solution worked for you.

Comment: Appreciate it.  I dont make a lot of API calls (once per day, one per shop per 250 orders from the last calendar day) but I want to stay on the safe side to avoid ny possible errors or issues

Answer (score 1):

When planning your capacity and rate limiting - at first you should estimate your data size, because strategy for couple shops with rarely over couple of pages each and thousands of shops with multiple pages is very different.

Because of Shopify's rate limiting is based on "Leaky bucket" algorithm with default bucket size of 40 (at the time of writing, [see official docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/rest-admin-api-rate-limits#general-api-rate-limits)) - you can make a burst of up to 40 api calls in a row without any rate limiting, that'll suffice for a few shops with a couple of pages each.

If you have/plan to have more than that (or just want to be polite) - easiest way is to make a separate queue for these tasks with a single worker, so that tasks do not run in parallel. Then add a `sleep(0.5)`(or more) after each api call - and you should not saturate your limit even if you have other arbitrary calls somewhere else in your app. But be ready to receive a rare `429 Too Many Requests`, in which case just wait a little more and repeat that call.

Comment: As for being polite. Because that's what I want.  I want to get the code to the point where if scaling is about to happen, I don't need to recode anything.  Would you think the way I have the while loop in the background job that triggers another background job, a good idea? Or, what you're saying is to rid that second background job and just let it run through in the single worker? Any special reasoning?

Comment: @uno if the second job does not access API - there's no big difference, but if it does - it's easier to make a single job. Other option is to place your own nginx reverse proxy with `limit_req` in front of shopify api that would throttle request rate and make jobs wait

Comment: Yes, this is tru.e  because of what Ashok supplied to me, I instead now am only using one job.  Plus multiple jobs require extra Dynos which is pointless unless its absolutely needed